# Flash AS3 ScrollPane / ScrollBar problem!

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, scroll

I have this scenery:

- 1 ScrollPane
- 1 UILoader.

And i do that:

myScrollPane.source = myUILoader;

Everything is ok here! (The contens apear correctly).

Im using UILoader as source because i need 'loadBytes' method to show my pre-loads ByteArrayData.

The problem is the SCROLLBAR of ScrollPane doesn't show the scroll handler when the content get out of wiew port.

Obs this doesn't work too, in any time, after load, on click , etc.

myUILoader.invalidate();
myUILoader.refreshPane();
myUILoader.update();

Any help , thanks!!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried listening to the progress event and finally to the complete event of your UILoader class to update your ScrollPane? You can use these event to call invalidate on your ScrollPane and not you UILoader.

Comment: thank's solved i remove uiloader and set de the ScrollPane source direct to a new BitMap. like this: ...source = new BitMap(myBitMapData).